# Electron App: Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, electron

I am writing code to load c++ dll from electron.I am using NaN and bindings (node-gyp) to achieve this. I am creating a 32 bit dll. Around 2-3 days before I was able to load the dll from electron. Suddenly I am now getting this error:
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I did run the following commands but they did not help:
node-gyp clean configure build --verbose --arch=ia32
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm install --arch=ia32 electron-prebuilt -g

Reinstalled node and electron as well.

Comment: Try installing and using 32-bit node

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-installing node. Here's what I did, it works for me

```
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm clean-install --arch=ia32
```

The first command set the node environment to 32bit. The second command re-install all the node packages that are 32bit compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me (node v18.14.0)

```
$ npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm ERR! `npm_config_arch` is not a valid npm option
```